# to attach file from drive to google site with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm trying to attach a file from drive to a google site with this script:

```
  function myFunction() {

  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-hZOMOQnNEDOU9sWEV5SzlXVTQ");
  var myFile = myFolder.getFilesByName("Data.txt").next();
  var myBlob = myFile.getBlob();

  var myPage = 

  SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/site/demo").getChildByName 
  ("home/demoFileCabinet");

  myPage.addHostedAttachment(myBlob);

  }
```

All the variables are OK, but "myPage.addHostedAttachment(myBlob)" give me an internal error.
The most curious thing is that sometimes run OK, but sometimes not. I don´t know what happens.

Could anybody give me some idea?. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already checkout the [Google Apps Script's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222)?

Comment: Yes, I opened an Issue Tracker with this internal error. But I haven't had any answers yet. Number: 68879309